# Determing the type of differential equation?

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to determine what type of differential equation this is.

e^-y(1+ y') =1

Then i need to find the particular solution subject to the initial condition of y(0) = -ln2

Any help would be appreciated. Im struggling on starting it

Answer (score 1):

Because the dot almost invisible on $y$, I suppose that the ODE is :
$$e^{-y}\left( 1+\frac{dy}{dt}\right)=1$$
If the supposition is correct, this is a first order non-linear autonomous ODE.

The ODE is separable and so, easy to solve :
$$y=-\ln|1+c\: e^t|$$

Note : meanwhile User111111 corrected his wording for $y'$. So, my supposition was correct.

Comment: wow ok that was easy i dont know how i didnt see that, so non linear, non homogeneous, separable equation. So thats the general solution there? Also how did you seperate it?

Comment: $ 1+\frac{dy}{dt}=e^y\quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{dt}=e^y-1\quad\to\quad dt=\frac{dy}{e^y-1}$

Comment: Dont you usually separate it like q(x) and p(x)?

Comment: What are $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ ?

Comment: @ JJacquelin the two separate sections of the equation

Comment: The wording of your question was ambiguous because the symbol of the variable was not specified in it. So, one is allowed to use $t$ instead of $x$ or any other symbol.

Comment: yes true true...

Comment: Note that if you call $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ the two separate sections, this is not correct because at least one of them must include not only $x$ but also $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: Yeah i understand what you are saying

Comment: @ JJacquelinfrom dt=dy/e^y−1 did you integrate it there?

Comment: Also the two separate sections are not both containing the same variable. This cannot be $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ ,  but one with $y$ and the other with $x$. That is why we say that they are separated.

Comment: oh so for this its y and t as the variables

Comment: @User111111 : $t=\int \frac{dy}{e^y-1}+$constant. Integrate to obtain $t(y)$. Then inverse for $y(t)$.

Comment: ok then i can put in the intitial condition and find the value for C?

Comment: Yes, that is what can be done.